# How to refresh the page content after a Post submission on ASP.NET Core Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am using ASP Net Core, and I created a project with Razor Pages.

I have a page which lists products associated with the current user, and he can add a new product.

**After the `OnPost` method is called, I want to refresh the page so that it displays all the products of the user without requesting the database again**

Below is my current solution:

```
    public async Task OnGet()
    {
        var currentUser = await GetCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null)
            Products = await _dbContext.Products.Where(x => x.AtpUserId == currentUser.Id).ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task OnPost(Product product)
    {
        var currentUser = await GetCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null)
        {
            product.UserId = currentUser.Id;
            product.Currency = "USD";
            await _dbContext.Products.AddAsync(product);
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            Products = await _dbContext.Products.Where(x => x.UserId == currentUser.Id).ToListAsync(); // can I avoid this ?
        }
    }
```

I don't find how I achieve the same result without the last line which reloads the data from the database.

- I looked at some examples but examples from the scaffold pages all use an intermediate `Create` page, and then redirect to the `Index` page. I want the user to be able to create from the Index page
- I tried to replace the last line of the `OnPost` method by a call to `RedirectToPage("Index");` but the method `OnGet` is not called again and the table containing the products is empty on refresh. Why?

Comment: If `RedirectToPage("Index")` worked, `OnGet()` would be called in turn which would perform the database request too so this wouldn't do what you're looking for anyway. You might however get it to work with `RedirectToPage("./Index")`

Comment: Well, I tried and suprisingly `RedirectToPage("./Index")` also displays the page without the data loaded. Why did you think it would load the data instead of `RedirectToPage("Index")`

Comment: In some Microsoft samples, they're using `RedirectToPage("./Index")` so I thought you might give it a try.

Comment: Actually to make it work, you have to `return RedirectToPage("./Index");` (notice the `return`) and change the signature of `OnPost` to `public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(Product product)`

Comment: @Christian Your approach would still bring further memory for redirecting. He can just call OnGet within OnPost to perform the operations of the OnGet. More like saying, if he changes the return from void to `IActionAction`, he must do the same with OnGet, and then on his OnPost he must just say `return OnGet()`

Comment: @Christian indeed returning a `Task<IActionResult>` does the trick

Comment: lol! @user60762, your methods were only returning Task, so you can't return Redirection on a void method, if you get what I'm saying.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, That's a great question, Thanks for asking!

What you are trying to achieve cannot be done through redirecting. The database will be called once again and that's unavoidable. But there's another approach, which is what I'd recommend if you really don't want to request data from the database twice. Let's explore it below:

You will need to pass the `Products` data back to the model when `OnPost` is called. This means that you must bind that data so that it's passed with form data to the model on post submission.

First, mark your products property in your Razor Page Model with `[BindProperty]`, and then add an `<input type="hidden" value="@Model.Products" />` in your HTML. This will submit your `Products` data with form submission.

Now in your `OnPost`, Products will have a value because it will be binded. And by the Time `OnPost` returns `Page`, `@Model.Products` will have same values that were retrived from the initial `OnGet`. I have done this before, and it's worked, so I can assure you that it's going to work.

Here's some sample code:

```
public class SomePageModel{

  [BindProperty]
  public IList<Product> Products {get; set;}
  
  [BindProperty]
  public Product Product {get; set;}
  
  public async Task OnGet()
  {
      var currentUser = await GetCurrentUser();
      if (currentUser != null)
          Products = await _dbContext.Products.Where(x => x.AtpUserId == currentUser.Id).ToListAsync();
  }

  public async Task OnPost()
  {
      var currentUser = await GetCurrentUser();
      if (currentUser != null)
      {
          Product.UserId = currentUser.Id;
          Product.Currency = "USD";
          await _dbContext.Products.AddAsync(Product);
          await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
      }
  }
}
```

For Binding to work, you need to pass the data back to the Model, so include a hidden `<input />` for it:

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" asp-for="Products" value="@Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Products)" />
</form>
```

Then in your `OnPost()`, Just de-serialize it back to `List<Products>`

```
Products = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(FormInput.Products)
```

---

Another Approach I would use is this:

Add a method in page model called `GetProductsAsync(User currentUser)` like this:

```
public async Task<List<Product>> GetProductsAsync(User currentUser)
{
  return await _dbContext.Products.Where(x => x.AtpUserId == currentUser.Id).ToListAsync();
}
```

Then in your razor page .cshtml, call that method to get the list of products:

`var products = await Model.GetProductsAsync(Model.currentUser) // This will run everytime the page loads`

Then your model code would be like this:

```
public User currentUser { get; set; }

public async Task<List<Product>> GetProductsAsync(User currentUser)
{
  return await _dbContext.Products.Where(x => x.AtpUserId == currentUser.Id).ToListAsync();
}

public async Task OnGet()
{
    var currentUser = await GetCurrentUser();
}

public async Task OnPost(Product product)
{
    var currentUser = await GetCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser != null)
    {
        product.UserId = currentUser.Id;
        product.Currency = "USD";
        await _dbContext.Products.AddAsync(product);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that was possible. You might have forgot to add the product to the `Products` property though because if MVC can really manage to deserialize what's in the hidden input back to `Products` it still contains the products without the added product. Also in your code example you've written `asp-for="Products"` but probably meant `value="@Model.Products"` as you have written above.

Comment: Remember Product will be deserialized back to C# Objects, So it will be a matter of adding it to the Existing `Products` using `Products.Add(Product)`.

Comment: The idea is also for him to try it. I have done this before but not with Lists... But I don't think it will make much difference, let's let him try that and see what he gets

Comment: Thank you @MosiaThabo I tried your approach (with `value=@Model.Products"`) but the hidden field contains only the `ToString()` representation of the list `<input type="hidden" value="System.Collections.Generic.List1[MyProject.Models.Product]" id="Products" name="Products">`  So it is not working "easily" like this. However I found out this explanation for [how to bind complex collections](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding#binding-complex-collections) which might do the trick

Comment: Yes you need to serialize your Products into JsonString then pass it to value. You can use Newtonsoft for serializing your Products.

Comment: Is this solution better https://stackoverflow.com/a/55743079/191985 ?

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.Net Core Razor Pages you can have the page re-rendered or refreshed by returning the PageResult. This is done with `return Page();`

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
  {
      var currentUser = await GetCurrentUser();
      if (currentUser != null)
      {
          Product.UserId = currentUser.Id;
          Product.Currency = "USD";
          await _dbContext.Products.AddAsync(Product);
          await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
      }
      return Page();
  }
}
```

Comment: Returning `Page()` from the `OnPost()` method doesn't re-render or refresh the page, for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the best way to manage lists of elements on a webpage, is to manage them on client code, and just query the database when my users submit.

I'll try to elaborate further:

If you have a page where a list of elements is shown, and your users can add, modify or erase elements from there, the best way to to this (IMHO) is the following:

-Load the page with current info obtained from database (you can store a representation of that info in your client code, lets say, for example, on a JSON object).

-Let your user manage the info on the page. When he adds a new element, you update the info on your JSON object and reflect it on the screen, but don't get in contact with the database until changes are submitted.

-You make the same with updates or deletes, always maintaining the actual info in your main JSON object, but without calling the server for anything.

-When the operation is finished (and this can mean a lot of different things depending on your business model) you get your updated JSON object, with current complete list of elements, and send it to the server to apply changes on a unique database transaction.

This generates less network traffic, less database operations, is faster, more reliable,  allow an easier way to update the views, and can be almost completely managed through client code.

It cannot apply to certain scenarios, for example if your collection of elements need to be modified by different users at the same time, or by external events out of the current user interaction, but is a clean and efficient way to manage many simple user interactions which we use to make too complex on an unnecesary way.

Comment: I understand your advice and it makes perfect sense. I asked this question because I am trying to do my project in the simplest way possible using ASP.NET Core by default. Of course it is suboptimal and generates more network traffic and server load, but at least I can avoid learning Javascript (again) and getting lost in the hundreds of frameworks. You might ask why I care about doing one more database call then, and the fact is my initial solution seemed too "raw", I did not like duplicating the code of the Get method and found it strange that the Redirect method was giving me a blank page.

Comment: But this approach works with a single-page app approach, he is using the traditional Multi Page Site so it won't work.